# How to get Android camera output as Java short (not byte)?

Tags: java, android, android-camera

The default camera output in Android SDK is [byte](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Byte.html) NV21 format. Byte ranges from -128 to 127.  However most operations on pixels (filters etc.) are introduced as applied to positive values ranging from 0 to 255.

Is it possible to obtain the camera output as short data type array with values ranging from 0 to 255? Or is it possible to directly get unsigned char pointer in NDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are the same thing.  A byte is 0-256, or -128 to 127. The same bits can be interpreted in either way, that's the way 2's complement arithmetic works.  There's no conversion necessary.